# Improving Scrapy-Playwright performance

Tags: optimization, scrapy, playwright

Performance with scrapy-playwright seems very poor.
For instance I am scraping with the standard request and with playwright 'http://ipinfo.io/ip' where it's hard to have a simplier page.

The requests are simple the only aim is to route the request through playwrite or the standard scrapy downloader.

**Playwright**

```
def start_requests(self):
    for i in range(0, self.count):
        yield scrapy.Request(
            "http://ipinfo.io/ip", 
            callback=self.parse_ipinfo,
            dont_filter=True,
            meta={
                "playwright": True,
            },
        )
```

or

**Standard**

```
def start_requests(self):
    for i in range(0, self.count):
        yield scrapy.Request(
            "http://ipinfo.io/ip", 
            callback=self.parse_ipinfo,
            dont_filter=True,
        )
```

`self.count` is set at 10000 though the aim is only to be in a sufficiently long enough loop.

`self.parse_ipinfo` only logs the `response.body`

The difference in speed is massive :

- Playwright : 25 pages / min
- Standard : 2200 pages / min

Unfortunately, I am currently forced to go through Playwright (and not even for JS interpretation...) but it's completly killing my scraper's speed.

Is there anything I can do to improve it ?

*** first findings ***

Playing with the `REACTOR_THREADPOOL_MAXSIZE` can help through increasing the parallelism. By default the `REACTOR_THREADPOOL_MAXSIZE` is 10, increasing it to 100 allowed me to reach ~90 pages / min.